# C++ explicit constructor that takes a pointer

Tags: c++, instantiation, explicit-conversion

I've recently stumbled across an explicit constructor that receives a single pointer argument. I wonder if the explicit keyword is necessary in this case? as there is no constructor for a pointer so there cannot be any implicit conversion.

```
class Foo {
 public:
  explicit Foo(int* int_ptr);
}
```

Comment: Why would a pointer be different to any other constructor parameter?

Comment: Whether `explicit` is necessary is a different matter, and has nothing to do with the parameter being a pointer. It has to do with which implicit conversions you want to allow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code:

```
void f(Foo) {}

int main()
{
    int* p;
    f(p);
}
```

- Fails to compile with `explicit`.
- Happily compiles without it.

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://godbolt.org/g/ifikxh)